# React-Tabs Component Require is not defined Uncaught Reference error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use the React-tabs component from here.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs
I have included the react-tabs.js file in the head of my html and have simply copy-pasted the example given there(in the link).

I am getting the following error:
Uncaught Referenceerror: require is not defined.

Following is my code:

```
 import {Tab,Tabs,TabList,TabPanel} from 'react-tabs';
 var tabbed=React.createClass({
 render:function(){

return(

<Tabs onSelect={this.handleSelect}
selectedIndex={2}
>


<TabList>

<Tab>Foo</Tab>
<Tab>Foo1</Tab>
<Tab>Foo2</Tab>

</TabList>



<TabPanel>
<h2>Hello from Foo</h2>
</TabPanel>
<TabPanel>
<h2>Hello from Foo1</h2>
</TabPanel>
<TabPanel>
<h2>Hello from Foo2</h2>
</TabPanel>

</Tabs>


);  
}


});


ReactDOM.render(
<tabbed/>,
document.getElementById('example')
);
```

`

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your build process look like?

Comment: what do u mean? I am running this in the browser.

Comment: Yes, but the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) syntax is part of the ES2015 standard and currently not supported by most of the major browsers. For this reason, you would first transpile it to ES5 (which mostly represents the currently browser-supported state of JavaScript), e.g. using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Then you would resolve the dependencies (`require`) into one big file that the browser can work with, e.g. using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: could u post a detail answer?
I am already using babel as a transpiler.I have included it in the head of my html.
Could not understand what exactly you should do after that.

Comment: Have a look at the pages I linked in my previous comment. Both Babel and Browserify provide very good getting started guides, better than I could ever write here.

Comment: okay so u mean even transpiling the js file I am including -> react-tabs.js.In addition to the js file above?